# Как создать класс, в котором каждый метод выполняется в новом потоке (Qt, c++)?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

У меня есть программа которая время от времени выполняет разные команды. За вызов этих команд отвечает 1 класс(sender), а выполнять их должен другой(handler). Причем разные типы команд должны выполняться в разных потоках. Есть конечно способ поместить класс в поток через `QThread::moveToThread`, но мне удобнее все команды держать в одном классе, а не создавать под каждую команду по классу, так команд может быть много. Вопрос в том как поместить в объект `QThread` не класс целиком а только функцию из класса, чтоб ее потом можно было вызывать просто через emit?

Comment: Насчёт переноса в QThread функции не знаю. А вы не думали сделать отдельный исполнитель задач (крутящийся в потоке), вытаскивающий задачи из очереди и исполняющий их?. А в качестве задач использовать `std::function` в связке с `std::bind`

Comment: Для qt - `fork` ещё не ввели? Самая удобная функция. Быстро обверните в `fork` https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_parallel/node7.html

Comment: C fork выглядит так `void proc1(){ if (fork()==0) {   } }`. Ссылка на en-so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749071/fork-and-wait-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Ну мне бы хотелось это сделать средствами qt.

Comment: @nick_n_a А вы в курсе, что fork создает новый процесс? Про "удобство" я вообще молчу.

Comment: @VTT Я понял.. я думал тут и надо создавать новый thread.

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну да, тут и надо создавать новый thread. А лучше переиспользовать ранее созданные.

Comment: почитайте про qrunnable http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html и реализацию выполнения в QThreadPool. Каждая ваша команда должна будет наследоваться от qrunnable и выполняться в пуле.

Comment: QtConcurrent - это прямо ваше. Имменно методы вызываются в другой среде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызвать метод класса в отдельном потоке можно в наследнике QThread/QRunnable

Адаптер **Runnable** для вызова функции в отдельном потоке

```
#include <functional>
#include <QRunnable>

class Runnable : public QRunnable
{
public:
  std::function<void()> fp;

  explicit
  Runnable(std::function<void()> f) :
    fp(f) {
  }

  void run() {
    fp();
  }

};
```

Класс Caller с реализацией команд

```
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>

#include "runnable.h"

class Caller {
private:
  QThreadPool * pool;

  void execute(std::function<void()> f) {
    pool->start(new Runnable(f));
  }

  void call_normal() {
    qDebug() << "Caller::call_normal()";
  }

  void call_delay() {
    QThread::currentThread()->msleep(1000);
    qDebug() << "Caller::call_delay()";
  }

public:

  Caller() {
    pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
  }

  void call1() {
    qDebug() << "Caller::call1()";
    execute(std::bind(&Caller::call_delay, this));
  }

  void call2() {
    qDebug() << "Caller::call2()";
    execute(std::bind(&Caller::call_normal, this));
  }

};
```

Сам вызов

```
...
Caller c;
c.call1();
c.call2();
...
```

Comment: Вау, спасибо большое за такой полный ответ!